# SvelteKIt - Access session - Function called outside component

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit with Typescript. In $lib folder, I have an .ts file.

I try to acces the user/session from `'$app/stores'` in the .ts file.

```
import { get } from 'svelte/store';    
import { session } from "$app/stores";

function getUser(){
  const {user} = get(session);
  console.log(user);
}
```

But when the function is called, i get the follow error message in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function called outside component
> initialization

How can I slove this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know at which point you call `getUser`, but it may be at other times than component initialization (else you wouldn't get this error), which means you need to structure things a little differently.

[From the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores):

"...the stores are not free-floating objects: **they must be accessed during component initialisation, like anything else that would be accessed with `getContext`**. ...The stores themselves (...) **need to be called synchronously on component or page initialisation when $-prefix isn't used**. Use `getStores` to safely `.subscribe` asynchronously instead."

This means:

1. Don't use `session` in this context, use `getStores` and assign to session yourself: `const { session } = getStores()`
2. Make sure to call `const { session } = getStores()` during component initialization.

Example:

```typescript
import { get } from 'svelte/store';    
import { getStores} from "$app/stores";

function getUser() { // <- call this at component initialization
  const { session } = getStores();
 
  return {
    current: () => get(session).user
  }
}
```